# Switching audio output between Receiver and Speaker in iOS7 and above?

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudiosession

I have an audio player which has an option of switching the Audio Output from Speaker to Receiver/Earpiece (irrespective of whether headset is connected) when proximity sensor notifies 1. The following is my code for doing so.

```
- (void) switchAudioOutput:(NSString*)output{
    AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL success;
    NSError* error;

    if([output isEqualToString:keAudioOutputReciever]){
        //Force current audio out through reciever
        //set the audioSession override
        success = [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                             error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:%@",error);

        //activate the audio session
        success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
        else
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession active with override: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone");

    }else if([output isEqualToString:keAudioOutputSpeaker]){
        //set the audioSession override
        success = [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                                  error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:%@",error);

        //activate the audio session
        success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
        else
            NSLog(@"AVAudioSession active with override: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker");

    }
 }
```

This was based on the answer [Toggle Button route audio to speaker and receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25042249/toggle-button-to-route-audio-to-receiver-or-speaker-in-ios-7) and [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330777/avaudiosession-audio-session-services-switching-output-solved). I noticed that this only forces the Audio to Speaker alone but does not ensure that the route goes to receiver alone. Moreover while shifting to speaker I get the following error:

> AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort:Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-50 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -50.)"

Comment: I'm also geting exact same error. Did someone manage to solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out the answer by avoiding overrides for Receiver

```
- (void) setAudioSession:(NSString*)audioOutput{

        NSError* error;
        if([audioOutput isEqualToString:audioOutputSpeaker.lowercaseString]){

            //set the audioSession override
            if(![self setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                              withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker|AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                                    error:&error])
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord:%@",error);

            //activate the audio session
            if (![self setActive:YES error:&error])
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
            else
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession active with override: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone");
        }else if ([audioOutput isEqualToString:audioOutputReciever.lowercaseString]){
            //Force current audio out through reciever
            //set the audioSession override
            if(![self setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                              withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                                    error:&error])
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord:%@",error);

            if (![self overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone error:&error])
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error overrideOutputAudioPort to Reciever:%@",error);

            //activate the audio session
            if (![self setActive:YES error:&error])
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession error activating: %@",error);
            else
                NSLog(@"AVAudioSession active with override: AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this too and was trying to set the `mode` parameter so something potentially appropriate, e.g.

```swift
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                                                mode: .voicePrompt,
                                                options: .defaultToSpeaker)
```

And that would just throw me an error:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003329396 "(null)"
```

The audio was routing to the receiver rather than speaker with just the `category` parameter and with the `mode`, but when I randomly decided to try without the `mode` parameter but with the `options` parameter it worked fine!

So give this code a try if you struggle:

```swift
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord,
                                                options: .defaultToSpeaker)
```

Comment: Fascinating. is this the way in the latest iOS? I haven't touched this topic in a while