# How to find list of non ble bluetooth connected audio devices in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to list all the bluetooth connected audio devices. But there is no log in delegate functions. Also tried the solution from [Switching audio output between Receiver and Speaker in iOS7 and above?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141175/switching-audio-output-between-receiver-and-speaker-in-ios7-and-above)

Following is my code...

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth)
    } catch{
        print(error)
    }

    let manager = CBCentralManager.init(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    manager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    print(central.state)
}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
}

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    print(peripheral)
}

}
```

In my case, there is an audio player and a button(like the default airplay button in music). On clicking the button, it should display all the connected bluetooth devices. Is it possible to list all the devices? Also I cannot use Apple's MKVolumeView because I have to further create a cordova plugin.

Comment: There is Objective-C solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/20898939/1459192. Hope you can easily convert.

Comment: And also this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636637/possible-to-generate-a-list-of-connected-bluetooth-devices-for-ios

Comment: Audio is not suited for Bluetooth Low-Energy, and CoreBluetooth is ONLY for Bluetooth Low-Energy. Check with `AVAudioSession`.

Comment: @tech4242 Thanx for the reply. Though my problem is still not solved. I had already tried the solutions given in links you gave . Also, I have edited my question to be bit more specific.

Comment: @Larme Thanx for the reply. Though my problem is still not solved. Also, I have edited my question to be bit more specific.